# R 3.4.0 - Windows - filter function (in dplyr package) freezing RStudio

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

When executing filter(cran, package == "swirl"), I'm running into the following error. After the error occurs, if I try to run the code again, RStudio freezes.

```
Error in filter_imp(.data, quo) : function 'bindrcpp_rcppExport_validate' not provided by package 'bindrcpp'

In addition: Warning message: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, : there is no package called ‘bind rcpp’
```

The solutions I've tried:

1) dplyr:filter(cran, package == "swirl") to makes sure I'm using the dplyr filter and not the stat filter.
2) install the bindr package and the bindrcpp package.

One potential issue is that when I load the bindrcpp package after installing it, it says

```
Error in library(bindrcpp) : there is no package called ‘bindrcpp’
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you updated dplyr but didn't get all the updated dependencies. Try `install.packages("bindrcpp")`. Then restart Rstudio. If you installed the package, then you shouldn't get the "no package" error. If the package fails to install, give the error message here.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick. To be honest, I'm pretty confident I've tried installing that package in the past, then loading it. This time it worked. I appreciate the quick response.